# Prove that nand is functionally complete

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can anyone explain to me how to

> Prove that nand is functionally complete.
>
> (To wit: if we let $p ∗ q$ mean $¬(p ∧ q)$, show that the other connectives, $∧$, $∨$, $¬$ and $→$ are expressible in terms of $∗$.)

I understand that logical function on a fixed set of inputs has a finite number of cases, but unsure how to put that into context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$¬p\equiv¬(p ∧ p)$

$p ∧ q\equiv¬(¬(p ∧ q))$

$p∨q\equiv¬(¬p ∧ ¬q)$

$p→q\equiv¬p∨q$

Therefore nand is functionally complete.

Comment: Forgive me for being pedantic but shouldn't those equality signs be equivalence signs (ie. $\equiv$ ) instead?

Comment: @DanielMak OK, I edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielMak: That depends on context. In _logic_ one usually keeps the $=$ sign reserved for equality between terms such that there won't be any confusion when we get to predicate logic -- but if one is doing Boolean algebra (or digital circuits or whatever) there's nothing wrong with using $=$ to assert equality between truth values as well.

Comment: However, I would point out that this answer tacitly assumes that we already know $\{{\neg},{\land},{\lor},{\to}\}$ to be a functionally complete set. Hopefully the OP does already know that in his context.

Comment: Functional completeness means that you can implement all truth tables. You only show a reduction but not functional completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Two well-known basic facts:

> ***Lemma 1:*** Every boolean function can be represented as a [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form).

> ***Lemma 2:*** If $A = \{f_1, ... f_n\}$ if complete and every its function can be expressed in terms of functions from $B = \{g_1, ... g_m\}$, then $B$ is complete.

Lemma 1 $\implies \{\lnot, \lor, \land\}$ is complete.
The following formulas

$¬p\equiv¬(p ∧ p)$

$p ∧ q\equiv¬(¬(p ∧ q))$

$p∨q\equiv¬(¬p ∧ ¬q)$

together with Lemma 2 imply that $\{NAND\}$ is complete.

Comment: I do not follow. you have shown that $ \{ \neg$, NAND } expresses functions, which set is complete. but why NAND alone is enough

Comment: or you say, that you use $\neg$ after implementing it as NAND?

Comment: @dEmigOd yes, take a look at the very first formula